# How do I access paperclip file for pdf reader?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, paperclip, pdf-reader

I used the paperclip gem to add an upload function for a pdf file. The upload works, once uploaded, the file is saved to location

```
/system/uploaded_files/sources/000/000/006/original/file.pdf
```

now I am trying to access this using the pdf reader

```
require 'pdf-reader'
require 'open-uri'
reader = PDF::Reader.new(open('/system/uploaded_files/sources/000/000/006/original/file.pdf'))
```

I get the following error

```
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - /system/uploaded_files/sources/000/000/006/original/file.pdf
```

How do I access this file using the pdf-reader gem?

Comment: what if you pass it the instance?

Comment: i actually first tried creating an instance and passing it, did not work, so I tried the raw url.

Comment: how would you pass the instance though? as a url right. This is what i tried : reader = PDF::Reader.new(open(@uploaded_file.source.url))

Comment: Yep, I was thinking on that, is that folder public?

Comment: yes, in public folder

Comment: did you tried this in a console? out of rails?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your model is called `PDF` and the asset is saved as `file`.

```
class Pdf < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :file
end
```

Now try this:

```
p = Pdf.find(params[:id]) # get the object
reader = PDF::Reader.new(open(p.file.url))
```

Comment: i tried this but for some reason, the file that is picked up still says "No such file or directory - /system/files/sources/000/000/009/original/abcd.pdf?1410198957", however, when i run this on console after adding a public in front and removing the ?1410198957, it reads it. What us the issue here?

Comment: not sure where you are doing it - controller? If it works in console, it should work within your code as well. There could be some problem in the query where you get the record. Are you sure that you are using `p.file.url` and not `p.file.path`. Try printing `p.file.url` just before the reader code and see if that URL is correct/accessible.